# Nested mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema that models a user in a social network. 
In it i want to save an array of all the chats that a user has, a chat consists of a responent (the user a user is chatting with), and an array that represents the conversation.

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email        : String,
    chats         : [{ respondent : String, conversation : [{ message: String, author : String}]}],
});
```

How do i find an item in chats that contains a perticular respondent? In the item found, id like to push a message to the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mention any key for inner chat. Specify like this :

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        email        : String,
        chats         : [
         { respondent : String, 
          innerChat:[{ message: String, author : String}]}
       ],
    });
```

Query for adding document solution is:

```
var document={
email:"abc@gmail.com",
chats:[{respondent:"UserName",innerChat:[{message:"hello",author:"authorName"}]}]
}
db.collection.insert(document);
```

Query for finding document on inner query

```
db.collection.find({"chats.innerChat.author":"authorName"});
```

Comment: Thanks i forgot to put the key, my issue is that i need to find the innerChat (or conversation as i called it) using the respondent.

Comment: you mention that you want to push items in the inner chat.please update you question

Comment: well, to be fair i said "Using a respondent, how do i push items to the inner chat" but i see where u are comming from, question updated.

Comment: I don't want to look for an author, but rather the item that contains a perticular respondent and push back a json object to the conversation in that item.